# R Data table user defined function is slow

Tags: r, data.table, igraph

I have two data tables `dt1` and `dt2`.  `dt1` is constructed from a list of individual indicators `ii` and a list of time indicators `tt`.  An example with 3 individuals and two time periods is:

```
library(data.table)
ii_ind = c(1,2,3)
tt_ind = c(2010,2011)
dt1 = merge(x=data.frame(ii =ii_ind) , y = data.frame(jj=ii_ind))
dt1 = merge(x=dt1 , y = data.frame(tt = tt_ind))
dt1 = as.data.table(dt1)
dt1 = dt1[ii != jj]
```

`dt1` represents dyads in a dynamic network (indicator for edges is in a fourth column, but is irrelevant to what I am trying to do here).

`dt2` has three columns indicating individual `ii`, time `tt`, and an integer variable `zz`.  For example:

```
dt2 = data.table(ii = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), 
                 tt = c(2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2010,2010,2011,2011,2010,2011),
                 zz = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,3))
```

I want a new column in `dt1`, say `count.zz`, that counts the number of instances that `(ii,tt)` and `(jj,tt)` have a `zz` in common.  This is how I do it:

```
setkey(dt1,ii,jj,tt)
setkey(dt2,ii,tt)
dt1[,count.zz:= as.integer(0)]
count.zz.fun = function(z.ii,z.jj,z.tt){
  return(length(intersect(dt2[.(z.ii,z.tt),zz],dt2[.(z.jj,z.tt),zz])))
}
dt1[,count.zz := count.zz.fun(ii,jj,tt), by = c("ii","jj","tt")]
```

In the example we have `count.zz=2` for `ii=1,jj=2,tt=2010` as both `(ii,tt)` and `(jj,tt)` have `zz=1` and `zz=2` in common.  `count.zz=0` for `ii=1,jj=3,tt=2010`, since `zz=1` and `zz=2` for `(ii,tt)` which does not intersect `(jj,tt)`'s set of `zz`, namely `zz=3`.

I am wondering if there is a faster way of doing this.  With `2.3` million rows in `dt1` and `zz` ranging from `1` to `100`, the above operation takes about `2-3 hours` to run on a standard desktop PC.

I have tagged `igraph`, as the above structure is a network and there might be a faster way of doing this using `igraph` that I am unaware of.

@Ryan suggested using `sum(a %in% b)` rather than `length(intersect(a,b))`.  Here is a comparison of the two functions:

```
library(tictoc)
N = 1000000
R = 1000
a = seq(from=1,to=N, by = 2)
b = seq(from=1,to=N, by = 3)

t = tic() 
for (rr in 1:R){
  sum(a %in% b)
}
t_sum = toc(t)

t = tic() 
for (rr in 1:R){
  length(intersect(a,b))
}
t_intersect = toc(t)
```

Results:

```
> t_sum = toc(t)
26.94 sec elapsed

> t_intersect = toc(t)
30.87 sec elapsed
```

@Ryan's suggestion improves speed by ~13-14%.

Comment: if `a` and `b` have all unique elements, `sum(a %in% b)` is equal to `length(intersect(a, b))` and faster

Comment: do you mind sharing more details abt `dt2`? if it is not too large, maybe u can share it using `dput`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the dimensions of your `dt2`, you might want to perform a self join on `dt2` to generate all pairs of ii and jj for combinations of tt and zz. Then perform a join and calculating the length using `by=.EACHI`

```
#find all pairs of ii and jj for combis of tt and zz
reldt <- dt2[dt2, .(ii=x.ii, jj=i.ii, tt, zz), on=.(tt,zz)]

#join and find the number of occurrence
reldt[dt1, on=.(ii,jj,tt), .N, by=.EACHI]
```

output:

```
    ii jj   tt N
 1:  2  1 2010 2
 2:  3  1 2010 0
 3:  1  2 2010 2
 4:  3  2 2010 0
 5:  1  3 2010 0
 6:  2  3 2010 0
 7:  2  1 2011 2
 8:  3  1 2011 1
 9:  1  2 2011 2
10:  3  2 2011 0
11:  1  3 2011 1
12:  2  3 2011 0
```

Comment: This is fast.  My problem takes only a few seconds now.  I am unable to share the contents of my data, but I can tell you that `dt2` has around 12,000 rows, so it is small relative to the number of rows that we are updating in `dt1`.